# Onscreen object move with scroll move/clientX

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have the fully functional code on IE7:

```
function ScrollControl()
{
   var obj = window.event.srcElement;
   var evento = obj.componentFromPoint(event.clientX,event.clientY);
   window.div_cabecalho.scrollLeft = obj.scrollLeft;
}
```

The ScrollControl is an function called in my onscroll attribute in an table and it makes the table title moves with the table content.
It works in IE, but in another browsers don't. I have tried variations like pageX to get the position but it always return undefined value.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbnjuhvs/) with full code

Comment: it works in firefox and in chrome. What else kind of browser do you need to test?

Comment: no, it doesn't work. Only the table content moves, not the table title/description.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using jquery

```
$('#div_grid').on('scroll', function () {
 $('#div_cabecalho').scrollLeft($('#div_grid').scrollLeft());
});
```